# how to make a file uploading detail

Tags: php, jquery

i am implementing a uploading box in my site,The file got uploaded successfully but i want to make a box or loading bar which shows me detail of uploading like how much file is uploaded or what is the speed of transfer,I am bit confused with this, i want to know what is the logic behind this,Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). In modern browsers it supports the `progress` event:

```
$(...).ajaxForm({
    ...,
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
       ...
    }
});
```

While there *are* ways to do it with server-side code they usually require webserver plugins and are a huge mess as they require constant polling for the upload progress, an information that is already available locally. So simply provide the progress display only for people with modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/). It has lot of features like real time indicators, drag n drop etc.

Pls check it, hope this will help you.